# How to write this statement without if/else?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

So my company is moving to this hyper functional programming forbidding if/else and nested ternary. The function is this:

```
const getUrlData = (url) => {
        if (!url) {
            return { finUrl: url, newTab: false };
        } else {
            if (url.startsWith("~")) {
                return { finUrl: url.substring(1), newTab: true };
            } else {
                return { finUrl: url, newTab: false };
            }
        }
    };
```

How could I do this same without `if's/elses` and nested ternary so the code doesn't look like #@$%@@? For now it's a puzzle for me, I can't solve.

Comment: Forbidding conditions is bare nonsense and a misunsderstanding of FP.

Comment: Forbidding nested ternaries is an arbitrary decision at best and somebody's own unchallenged opinion at worse. There are ways to make them look absolutely readable but "tools" like Prettier will get in the way unfortunately.

Comment: You should take questions like this to the people making the rules. Either they will help you or you'll find out it's not as "forbidden" as you thought. At any rate, they should be made aware of difficulties people are facing with policies, so they can make adjustments or improve training or communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) you can rid of any condition, but you will have to transpile it somewhere to get browser support.

```js
const getUrlData = (url) => ({
  finUrl: url?.replace(/^~/, ''),
  newTab: !!url?.startsWith("~")
})
```

Transpiles to:

```js
const getUrlData = (url) => ({
    finUrl: url === null || url === void 0 ? void 0 : url.replace(/^~/, ''),
    newTab: !!(url === null || url === void 0 ? void 0 : url.startsWith("~"))
});

console.log(getUrlData(undefined))
console.log(getUrlData('foo'))
console.log(getUrlData('~bar'))
```

Comment: I am on tsx so no problem

Comment: If you add a `url=''` default parameter, you can skip the `!!` as well. (But, `finUrl` will have `''`when null is passed)

Comment: @adiga good idea, because '' will be falsy the same as undefined.

Comment: I meant the boolean returned by `url.startsWith("~")` should be enough. No need to `!!` and `?.` I don't think OP will pass something other than string, null and undefined to this function

Comment: yes, that's much better, but changes the behaviour of finUrl and still doesn't allow `null`

Comment: FYI `x == null` is true if `x` is either `null` or `undefined`. This is one use case where double equality is actually ok and desirable. See [Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-equality-checks-exceptions) — In your example you unconditionally return `undefined` when `url` is nil but that would equate to mutating data to some extent. This would be a slight improvement in my opinion: `url == null ? url : url.replace(...)`

Comment: Just realised I made a comment on something that was transpiled sorry about that. Leaving the comment as it may be useful anyway. Otherwise happy to take it out, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

First, lets simplify the code by inverting the if and realising that 2 of the paths through return the same response:

```
const getUrlData = (url) => {
    if (url && url.startsWith("~")) {
        return { finUrl: url.substring(1), newTab: true };
    }
    return { finUrl: url, newTab: false };
};
```

It's now obvious how to use just a single ternary expression:

```
const getUrlData = (url) => (url && url.startsWith("~"))
                   ? { finUrl: url.substring(1), newTab: true }
                   : { finUrl: url, newTab: false };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, splitting the function into smaller ones:

```
const emptyUrl = (url) => ({ finUrl: url, newTab: false })

const nonEmptyUrl = url => url.startsWith('~') ? { finUrl: url.substring(1), newTab: true } : {
  finUrl: url,
  newTab: false
}
const getUrlData = (url) => url ? nonEmptyUrl(url) : emptyUrl(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for it:

```js
const getUrlData = (url) => {
let condition = url && url.startsWith("~") ? true : false;
    return { finUrl: condition ? url.substring(1) : url, newTab: condition }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single conditional operator (and you can use `?.` to make it slightly shorter.)

```
const getUrlData = (url) => {
  return (url && url.startsWith("~")) // or just `url?.startsWith("~")`
    ? { finUrl: url.substring(1), newTab: true }
    : { finUrl: url, newTab: false };
};
```